# Python-HTML-How to strip out content in between tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

**What I'm doing:** I'm writing a webpage extractor to gather weather data. This is what I did so far:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# open the webpage and assign the content to a new variable
base = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.weather.com/weather/today/Beijing+CHXX0008:1:CH')
f = base.readlines()
f = str(f)


soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

rn_base = soup.find_all(itemprop="temperature-fahrenheit")
```

If you `print` the variable `rn_base`, you get: `[<span class="wx-value" itemprop="temperature-fahrenheit">75</span>]`, which i think is a list with only one element. The number `75` is my objective.

**Question:** I tried several ways to obtain the number but failed. They are, namely, 1) use `str.join()` to convert `rn_base` to a string, but failed because `rn_base` is a `ResultSet` object; 2)use index slicing, but because it's not a string subject, failed. 3)use `get_text()` as specified in [beautifulsoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text), but got `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rn_base is a **resultSet** object so even if the result is just one it assumes that there can be many result.So,

```
for rn in rn_base
Print rn.string
```

This for loop will extract each line form the result (When they have multiple occurrence of "temperature-fahrenheit")

As you told you are trying for weather data I think it is better to use `find()` with limit than `find_all()`

Comment: Thank you! Was really confused by the `resultset` class.